# Responsive Scrolling - setWantsLayer Webkit problems

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, scroll, layer

My project is on base SDK 10.6 built in Xcode 3 - it’s important that it is a universal binary that also works with PPC.

In 10.9 my application has really jerky scrolling compared to Safari - if I add

[self setWantsLayer:YES]; the scrolling is super fast like Safari, great!

However I get visual glitches when scrolling, see screenshot of eBay where the legal image which was supposed to be fixed at the bottom of the page keeps repeating.

I know setWantsLayer isn’t supposed to be used with a webKit, but is there anyway to stop these visual glitches or is there another way to get the smooth scrolling without using setWantsLayer.

[image: Issue with eBay]

Above is an issue with eBay when scrolling and below is an issue with Twitter while scrolling, happens on various websites especially with fixed objects.

[image: Issue with Twitter]

Issue with Twitter

Answer (score 0):

Actually I originally thought the below solution was a solution without realising that I was back to the horrible jumpy scrolling. I leave it for reference.

I had the same problem you seems to have here.

I found that if I implemented the `canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer` in the subclass my glitches with the rendering were fixed.

so in the initWithCoder/initWithFrame method call:

```
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
```

then implement canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer

```
- (BOOL)canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer {
    return YES;
}
```

You need to subclass the webView. I also found that works equally well if instead you subclass the NSView below and do the same in the NSView subclass but since I don't understand why that works my suggestion is to subclass the webView.

I hope it helps you and helps others.